# Edit hist file to make a domain like facebook.com display my own html/php file

Tags: php, html, localhost

When I type facebook.com for example, I want to display my own content and not facebook's content. How can I modify my host files to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Put the following in your hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   facebook.com
```

That will direct all traffic from `facebook.com` to `127.0.0.1` (`localhost`). If you don't have a web server running on that IP then you can change it.

Comment: But then how do I point to the file I want to display when facebook.com is loaded?

Comment: You need to set up a web server. If you're on windows take a look at [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/).